# Group by non aggregate condition

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, conditional-statements, having

Is it possible to have non-aggregate condition on groups?
For example we have:

```
Table1(firstName, lastName, gender)
```

And we **group by** `firstName` and then by `lastName`, but we want only the groups having at least 5 males in it. Or another example is the groups without any male or other conditions like that.
Actually I solved it by using case when, but I'm looking to see if there is straight solution for it.
Another Form of this problem is when we want only the groups which contains at least one person older than 18, or any question like that.

Comment: By determining the number of males, wouldn't you need to include an aggregate to `COUNT` the number of males?

Comment: You can have pre-aggregate filtering with `WHERE` and/or post aggregate filtering with `HAVING`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is anything like your 'solution using case', but I think this is the most straightforward way to do it.

Basically, instead of just counting, you can sum the number of rows that match a condition, so the pattern is always: `SUM(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 [ELSE 0] END`. In the `HAVING` clause, you can filter by such aggregations.

Since `count` doesn't count `null`s, you could also write it as `COUNT(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 [ELSE null] END)`. This method is arguably more clear than the `SUM` way, but I'm more used to that one.

```
SELECT
  FirstName, LastName
FROM
  Table1
GROUP BY
  FirstName, LastName
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 5
```

The above condition is for 'at least 5 males'.

To write 'exacty 3 woman and at least one person older than 18', you could do it like this:

```
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3
  SUM(CASE WHEN Age > 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
```

Those conditions work separately, so in the condition above, the 18 year old person could be one of the three women or a guy. But you can also combine the conditions inside the case. For instance: 'at least 5 men who are 18 or older':

```
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' AND Age >= 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 5
```

I hope these examples will help you find the condition you need.

Comment: Thank you. It was exactly what I was looking for. But I have another question. What about if we want to group by list A but only the groups which include at least n member of list B.